# How to check if a device is compatible with a breadboard?

Tags: power, breadboard

I am just in the process of purchasing components for a control systems project but I am having trouble selecting a barrel jack that is compatible with a breadboard layout. I'm not sure if there is a specific standard or code that would tell me if the device had the correct pin pitch to fit a standard breadboard (if standard breadboards exist).

I found this on digikey and thought it might work, can anyone confirm? https://www.cui.com/product/resource/pj-102a.pdf

Thanks!

Comment: Connectors are almost never breadboard-compatible as their contacts are much too thick.

Comment: But surely some connectors are specifically designed for breadboards?

Comment: Breadboards are good for anything except high frequencies, high voltage, high current and high impedance.

Comment: No, all electronics are made for either soldering or crimping. People using breadboards are not a target audience.

Comment: Hmm fair enough

Answer (score 5):

If a connector you have does not directly fit in a breadboard, solder a couple of wires to it, and poke the wires into the breadboard as required.

Comment: Hello Peter, thanks for the answer, I updated the link to a datasheet of the device rather than the digikey link. I would solder it but alas I have no solder and iron :(

Comment: The PCB layout on that datasheet indicates that the connector is not a good fit for a breadboard - breadboard holes are on 0.1" centers, and the connector pins are not.  If you are going to do anything with electronics, you WILL need a soldering iron, so get one now.

Answer (score 2):

I would propose to buy the jacks which are breadboard compatible, and also the soldering gun soon.

There are breadboard compatible DC jacks which are available from sparkfun and many more. Below is just one example.

[image]

---

[image]

Comment: The pictured item is not really that breadboard compatible, as evidenced by the fact that the *flattened* pins are flattened in two orthogonal axis.  You don't want to insert these the "wide way" between contacts.

Comment: CUI PJ-102A (Digikey CP-102A-ND )  is another socket like that, and yeah the side pin is flattened the wrong way, but that can be corrected using pliers,